# Ncurses UI in a web browser

Tags: browser, ncurses

Is there any way to display an ncurses UI on a web browser? More specifically, if I run a program that has an ncurses UI on system X, can I display its UI on system Y through a web browser? Are there any tools available to do this?

Answer (score 3):

One possible option would be to use the [Secure Shell Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo?hl=en-US).

This would allow you to ssh into the machine in the browser and run the ncurses program.

Answer (score -3):

Perhaps you are looking for a ncurses web browser, like lynx?

[1] http://lynx.isc.org/lynx2.8.7/index.html